# How do I control autogenerated test targets in WebStorm?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, mocha.js, karma-runner, webstorm

I've just upgraded to WebStorm 2017.1 and suddenly I have these very nice "run this test" buttons in my test files:

[image: Run one test button]

However, any time I click one of these buttons, WebStorm is autogenerating a Mocha test target:

[image: autogenerated mocha test target]

The problem is, I'm using Karma for unit tests on this project. I've already followed [the instructions from the WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/running-unit-tests-on-karma.html) on setting up Karma. I've set up Karma defaults and manually created a Karma target (and removed all Mocha targets, as far as I know), but the IDE still tries to autogenerate a Mocha target any time I ask it to run tests.

How do I tell WebStorm that it should use Karma to run tests, rather than Mocha?

Comment: Note: [Cross-posted to WebStorm support community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000138464-How-to-prefer-Karma-when-autogenerating-unit-test-targets-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official answer from JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000138464-How-to-prefer-Karma-when-autogenerating-unit-test-targets-?page=1#community_comment_115000162970) as of 2017-03-23 is that running individual tests with Karma is not currently supported.  This feature request (about 2.5 years old now) is being tracked as [WEB-13173](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173).